# Переделать назначение кода python

Tags: python, массивы

есть код, выполняющий перебор комбинаций букв из массива (см. код) Работает правильно и алгоритм верен, мне нужно что бы данный код выполнял тоже самое только на основе слов вместо букв и выводил в строку комбинации слов через запятую: 
 **Пример:** Кошка собака дом => Кошка собака дом, кошка дом собака, кошка дом, кошка собака, кошка, собака кошка, собака дом, собака, собака дом кошка, собака кошка дом, дом, дом собака, дом кошка, дом собака кошка, дом кошка собака.

```
def gencombs(comb, lst, idx):
    if idx >= len(lst):
        print(comb)
    else:
        for i in range(len(comb),-1, -1):
            gencombs(comb[:i] + [lst[idx]] + comb[i:], lst, idx + 1)
        gencombs(comb, lst, idx + 1)

gencombs([],"abc", 0)
```

Comment: этот код делает то, что вам нужно, ничего переделывать не требуется

Comment: он разбивает слова на буквы и перебирает их, нужно что бы код перебирал слова, а не буквы

Comment: потому что вы его неправильно используете. Код перебирает не буквы, и не слова, а элементы списка. А уж результат зависит от того, какой список туда попадает

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, пример на основе фразы из 3 слов, к своему сожалению в синтаксисе пайтона не силён.

Comment: В любом случае, я очень благодарен вам за ответ, спасибо!

Comment: `gencombs([],['Кошка', 'собака', 'дом'], 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй лучше библиотеку `itertools`, там есть метод: `permutations`, который принимает в себя `iterable` (например массив) и количество перестановок
Пример:

```
from itertools import *

a = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'House']

a = permutations(a)
for i in a:
    print(''.join(list(i)), end=', ')
```

Выведет:

```
CatDogHouse, CatHouseDog, DogCatHouse, DogHouseCat, HouseCatDog, HouseDogCat
```

Comment: `list()` тут излишен

Comment: Это не все нужные результаты, нужны ещё из одного и из двух элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Ну там же и надо было спросить. Код перебирает элементы iterable
объектов (т.е. таких, из которых можно взять элементы по одному - по индексу или другими средствами) - в примере строка, но это может быть и список (строк или чего угодно)

```
gencombs([], ["Кошка", "собака", "дом"], 0)
```